# django reports access denied for user at localhost when I set HOST to 127.0.0.1

Tags: mysql, django

MY config:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'dbname',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '123123',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '3306', 
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=InnoDB',
            'charset' : 'utf8mb4',
            'use_unicode' : True,
        },
    },
}
```

The connection is ok.

When I change PASSWORD to a wrong password, it shows:

```
File "/Users/fluke/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

When I change HOST to a invalid value like "127.0.0.123" while keep the correct password. It shows:

```
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.123' (60)")
```

Which means the django does use the value I set. But why it reports "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1" ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally localhost and 127.0.0.1 are interchangeable, they usually mean the same thing. This error looks like it shows that Django is able to contact the MySQL server, but it is not able to authenticate.

I would suggest creating a separate MySQL user to use for this application. Instructions for doing that can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html):

Then, use those credentials in your config. Something like this:

```
    'NAME': 'dbname',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': 'NewUserName',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': 'NewPassword',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not
```